How to Set Up ACL in Apache Kafka Docker Image for Production with Best Practices?
I am working on setting up Access Control Lists (ACL) for an Apache Kafka deployment running in Docker containers. I aim to ensure secure communication and access control, adhering to production-grade best practices.
Here are the specifics of my setup:

I am using the official Apache Kafka Docker image (e.g., apache/kafka).
Kafka is deployed in a containerized environment, orchestrated by Docker Compose.

My questions are:

What are the steps to properly set up ACLs in this environment?
Are there any best practices for managing Kafka ACLs in a production-grade deployment?
How can I automate ACL provisioning, especially when managing multiple topics, groups, and users?
Are there any pitfalls to watch out for while using Kafka ACLs in a containerized production environment?

Environment Details:

Kafka version: 3.7.0

Thank you!
